# "OPTLINK : Error 118: Filename Expected" error for VisualD

Tags: visual-studio, d

I have been trying to setup VisualD with Visual Studio 2013 Shell but without any luck. The error trace which I get is:

```
Debug\ConsoleApp.exe not up to date: command line changed
------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Building Debug\ConsoleApp.exe...
OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.15
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2013  All rights reserved.
http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
OPTLINK : Error 118: Filename Expected 
Path=D:\dirs\installed\DLang\D\dmd2\windows\\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\\\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\dirs\installed\sbt\\bin;D:\dirs\installed\dub;D:\dirs\installed\DLang\dmd2\windows\bin;D:\dirs\installed\DLang\dm\bin;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\";D:\dirs\installed\DLang\D\dmd2\windows\bin;D:\dirs\installed\DLang\D\dm\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\dirs\installed\sbt\\bin;D:\dirs\installed\dub;D:\dirs\installed\DLang\dmd2\windows\bin;D:\dirs\installed\DLang\dm\bin;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\";D:\dirs\installed\DLang\D\dmd2\windows\bin;D:\dirs\installed\DLang\D\dm\bin;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;
^
Building Debug\ConsoleApp.exe failed!
Details saved as "file://D:\mydata\projects\visuald\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\Debug\ConsoleApp.buildlog.html"
Build time: 1 s
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Now I do know that `(` and `)` cause issues so I have tried to quote them in my `PATH` env variable *but* I'm not sure where the first part of the command which gets executed is coming from! That is, `Path=D:\dirs\installed\DLang\D\dmd2\windows\\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\\\bin` is not part of my `PATH` environment variable and hence I'm not sure how to quote them.

Any help on how to get VisualD running with Visual Studio 2013 shell would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: OPTLINK cannot deal with with the + character appearing in the path.

Comment: @HansPassant: I thought quoting the paths should do the trick? At least that's what I think I read in one of Walter's forum posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that Hans was right; the entry for Notepad++ in my path was creating issues. After removing that, I don't see the same error but a new one. Maybe that's a question for a separate thread...